# Qual é o nome do símbolo « »?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, pontuação

Aqui no Portuguese Language os símbolos `«` e `»` são muito utilizados para separar palavras do resto da frase, como por exemplo:

> De onde vem a palavra «oração»?

Qual é o nome desses símbolos? Existe alguma norma que regulamente o uso deles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chamam-se "aspas angulares", "aspas latinas" ou, em Portugal, simplesmente "aspas". Suas regras de uso são as mesmas que o nosso ⟨**“…”**⟩, uma vez que são basicamente duas formas diferentes do mesmo sinal de pontuação: a aspa comum.

Ambos têm a mesma origem, porém evoluíram em diferentes glifos pelas diferentes tradições ortográficas da Europa, até se padronizarem com a tipografia. Originalmente havia somente os glifos duplos, e mais tarde surgiram as formas simples para indicar diferentes níveis de citação.

- As *aspas angulares*, ou *aspas latinas*, (dupla:⟨**«…»**⟩, simples:⟨**‹…›**⟩) são as de tradição francesa. São usadas em boa parte da Europa ocidental e meridional (Portugal, Suíça, Galiza, País Basco, Grécia, Italia, etc.).
- As *aspas curvas*, ou *aspas inglesas*, (dupla:⟨**“…”**⟩, simples:⟨**‘…’**⟩) são as de tradição britânica. São usadas no continente americano, na Índia, e atualmente na África do Sul, além de em outros países com influência britânica.
- As *aspas alternadas*, ou *aspas alemãs*, (dupla:⟨**„…“**⟩, simples:⟨**‚…‘**⟩) são as de tradição germânica. São usadas na Alemanha, Holanda, Israel, países eslavos, e tradicionalmente na África do Sul.
- As *aspas retas* (dupla: ⟨**"…"**⟩, simples:⟨**'…'**⟩), padronizadas pelas máquinas de escrever e a codificação ASCII, são glifos que servem para representar tanto aspas, quanto apóstrofos e riscas, e não há diferença entre o glifo que abre e o que fecha o par (ambos são os mesmos).
- Algumas tradições tipográficas variam quanto à orientação das aspas. Alguns lugares usam as aspas apontadas para dentro ⟨**»…«, ”…“, „…“**⟩, outros para a direita ⟨**»…», ”…”, „…”**⟩. As aspas alternadas são, por padrão, apontadas para dentro. As aspas retas não possuem variação de orientação (pois são retas).

Além disso, cada ortografia varia ao definir as aspas para cada nível de citação. No padrão americano (e brasileiro) são usadas aspas duplas na citação externa e aspas simples na citação interna ⟨“…‘…’…”⟩. Na Inglaterra é o contrário (simples fora e duplas dentro). Alguns países eslavos combinam a tradição germânica com a francesa usando aspas alternadas como externas e as angulares como internas ⟨„…«…»…“⟩.

### As aspas no Brasil

O uso no Brasil das aspas curvas (ou, mais recentemente, as aspas retas), de tradição inglesa, como a forma única popularizou-se recentemente, talvez por ser tendência na América Latina por influência dos Estados Unidos.

Machado de Assis usou "aspas inglesas" em seu [manuscrito](http://servbib.academia.org.br/arquivo/asp/zoom.asp?item=5939&imagem=10661&zoom=1&content=image/jpeg) de Memorial de Ayres, mas a editora publicou a [versão final](https://archive.org/stream/3438833#page/n11/mode/2up) com «aspas angulares». Se vasculhar mais seus rascunhos, verá que Machado usava majoritariamente aspas inglesas, enquanto que as editoras e jornais usavam as angulares.

Em jornais do início do século passado você pode encontrar as duas formas sendo usadas:

[image: Jornal O Globo de 30 de Julho de 1938]

O [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) anglófona sobre as aspas fala melhor sobre sua origem e seu uso pelo mundo.

Answer (score 4):

Não consegui encontrar os nomes em Português, mas em Inglês eles são:

- `«`: [Left-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/pt/00AB/), Número Unicode `U+00AB`
- `»`: [Right-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/pt/00BB/), Número Unicode `U+00BB`

Ambos estão descritos [no documento de caracteres do *Latin-1 Suplement*](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) e também podem ser [chamados genericamente de *Quotation Marks*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=lxndiWaFMvMC&pg=PA432&lpg=PA432&dq=whats%20the%20use%20of%20left-pointing%20double%20angle%20quotation%20mark&source=bl&ots=Ndrw1FQ2Du&sig=XCeWEMxFAIXq5r-mz-wuSl_A5X0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimpPWoq7fWAhWCfZAKHctVBGcQ6AEISjAF#v=onepage&q=double%20angle%20quotation%20marks&f=false) (aspas).

---

Como curiosidade, nos links acima também há a menção a caracteres muito parecidos:

- [Much Less-Than](https://unicode-table.com/pt/226A/) e [Much Greater-Than](https://unicode-table.com/pt/226B/), que são um pouco mais "largos": `≪` e `≫`
- [Left Double Angle Bracket](https://unicode-table.com/pt/300A/) e [Right Double Angle Bracket](https://unicode-table.com/pt/300B/), que são um pouco mais "alongados verticalmente": `《` e `》`

Comment: "Quotation mark" é "aspa" em inglês. O último par de glifos que você comentou, os mais "alongados verticalmente", são derivados das aspas angulares da ortografia europeia, e são usadas na ortografia oriental (japonesa, chinesa, etc.) para marcar o títulos de obras. No Japão, trechos são citados entre 「...」, enquanto que títulos de obras são citados entre 《...》. Por exemplo: *O verso「Armas e barões assinalados」, é o primeiro de《Os Lusíadas》*. O penúltimo par de glifos que você citou, os mais "largos", são derivados do sinal maior-que e menor-que e não são relacionados a citação.

Comment: @Seninha Muito interessante saber que existem tantos tipos de aspas. Atualizei a resposta com a tradução correta, obrigado!